# how to get large data (json) from a specified url in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a PHP application and I need it to take a large JSON response from a URL. With curl, when I use it from the terminal everything goes as expected. But PHP curl does not get the whole file. It looks like it is truncated.

The curl command I use from the terminal is:

```
 curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch' resultsURL --compressed
```

where resultsURL is the URL I want to get the JSON from.

This usually gives me back about 10,000kb (9-10mb), but from PHP curl I get at most 400-500kb.

How can I get the whole file?

(exec is not an option)

Comment: you run php script from browser or `cli`?

Comment: I use Firefox, is there a difference?

Comment: Ok, if you call script from browser, then @AZinkey answer must help you. If not secret, what is the purpose of downloading this json file?

Comment: @maximkou Basically i don't need to download it. It is an api call and i just need to get some of the info it has inside this json.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit(0);
    $url  = 'http://www.example.com/a-large-file.json';
    $path = '/path/to/a-large-file.json';
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w+');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This outputs an empty json file. And when i use the headers i provide for compression in curl it outputs to the file what i was getting before.

Comment: can you share your json file link ?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=dcbc9d20-c3be-47f4-965f-d72961b76bb1

Comment: above url give empty result, is it required auth ?

Comment: Oh yea, i forgot about that. if i remember well it is an one time link or ip binded. try this one. I haven't used it. http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=0f554ce3-4d81-4324-977e-4c479f35780f